# Selecting values from lists to be put in graphs

Tags: python, list, graph

How would i select only the column with the salary numbers in it e.g 29000,24000 for inse

3

```
def read_file():
    i

    for row in infile:
        if not row.startswith('#'):
            row = row.rstrip('\n').split(', ')
            emp_data_list.append(row)
    infile.close()
```

Comment: Can you show how you are reading the data in? How is `emp_data_list` stored?

Comment: is that alright now?

Comment: Yup it's better. Your `salaries = (emp_data_list[item][4])` statement is wrong. `()` parenthesis are used to create `tuple`s in python. You were simply replacing `salaries` with a new `tuple` object every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have list of lists where every element of the list is a row, try:

```
salaries = [int(salary) for emp_no, name, age, pos, salary, yrs_emp in emp_data_list]
```

OR

```
salaries = [int(stuff[4]) for stuff in emp_data_list]
```

This should give you all of the salaries in your data. This is using list comprehension.

Comment: yeh this works the only problem is the values are printed:  ['29000', '24000', '42000', '21000', '53000', '42000', '50000', '33000', '38000', '22000', '19000', '23000', '44000', '32000', '28000'] which makes it hard to put into the graph as it recognises it as string and it messes with matplotlib, any solutions

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Not sure if you got the correct thing working or not but I updated my answer.